# Recursively renaming folders to @eaDir

Tags: directory, rename

I'm trying to use a thumbnail generator python script I found on GitHub, which works awesomely.

It generates thumbnails in a folder called `eaDir_temp`, which then needs to be renamed on the NAS to `@eaDir` from a terminal. The author provides a command for this:

```bsh
find . -type d -name 'eaDir_tmp' -exec mv '{}' @eaDir \;
```

Unfortunately, for each subfolder containing photos, it returns:

```
mv: cannot move ‘./subfolder/eaDir_tmp’ to ‘@eaDir/eaDir_tmp’: Directory not empty
```

What should I do instead?

Comment: Is it correct to say that the `eaDir_temp` directory has to be renamed only? I.e. should `./subfolder/eaDir_tmp` simply become `./subfolder/@eaDir`? Or is it meant to me moved to the current wotking directory (`.`)?

Comment: `./subfolder/eaDir_tmp` should become `./subfolder/@eaDir`. `.` Is simply meant to denote that the search applies from the current folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the curious, what is likely happening: the command

```sh
find . -type d -name 'eaDir_tmp' -exec mv '{}' @eaDir \;
```

moves every `./whatever/eaDir_tmp` directory it finds (i.e. the `eaDir_tmp` component) to the current working directory: `./whatever/eaDir_tmp` → `./@eaDir`. (Because `@eaDir` is seen by `mv` as a path component relative to the current working directory).

The first time, this creates `./@eaDir`, if it doesn't exist yet.

The second `./whatever/eaDir_tmp` found is moved *into* `./@eaDir`, because the target directory given to `mv` (`@eaDir`) exists at this point: `./whatever/eaDir_tmp` → `./@eaDir/eaDir_tmp`.

Further `./subfolder/eaDir_tmp` found are moved into `./@eaDir` as well, and this step fails because `./@eaDir/eaDir_tmp` already exists and is not empty.

---

What you can do: if your `find` implementation supports the `-execdir` action:

```sh
find . -depth -type d -name 'eaDir_tmp' -execdir mv '{}' @eaDir \;
```

`-depth` is actually only needed in case of nested `eaDir_tmp` directories (e.g. `./whatever/eaDir_tmp/whatever/eaDir_tmp`).

Contrary to `-exec`, `-execdir` runs the specified command from the directory containing the matched file (and not from `find`'s current working directory).

If your `find` doesn't support the non-standard `-execdir`:

```sh
find . -depth -type d -name 'eaDir_tmp' \
  -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%/*}/@eaDir"' mysh {} \;
```

Or, to avoid starting a shell for every single found directory:

```sh
find . -depth -type d -name 'eaDir_tmp' -exec sh -c '
  for dir
  do
    mv "$dir" "${dir%/*}/@eaDir"
  done' mysh {} +
```

Comment: `find . -depth -type d -name 'eaDir_tmp' -execdir mv '{}' @eaDir \;` works perfectly, thank you!